# typescript legacy js lib extension issue

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I need some help with imports, I am using @types/leaflet that defines a type

```
export namespace Icon {
    interface DefaultIconOptions extends BaseIconOptions {
        imagePath?: string;
    }

    class Default extends Icon<DefaultIconOptions> {
        static imagePath?: string;
        constructor(options?: DefaultIconOptions);
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to use the following libreray which extends the Icon behavior: https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-fa-markers
The issue is that it's plain JS and the type is not defined in @types...
node_modules/leaflet-fa-markers/L.Icon.FontAwesome.js

```
L.Icon.FontAwesome = L.Icon.extend({

    options: {
        popupAnchor: [0, -50]
    },

    createIcon: function () {

        var div = document.createElement('div');
...
```

So far, I've imported js and css in .angular-cli.json, but can't figure out how to import it in my service... So far I've imported the js lib

```
import 'leaflet-fa-markers';
//...
        let marker = new L.Marker([ lat, lng], {
          icon: L.icon.fontAwesome({
            iconClasses: 'fa fa-info-circle', // you _could_ add other icon classes, not tested.
            markerColor: '#00a9ce',
            iconColor: '#FFF'
          }),
          draggable: true});
```

But I get the error:

```
src/app/_services/canimap.service.ts (99,24): Property 'fontAwesome' does not exist on type '(options: IconOptions) => Icon<IconOptions>'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have found is to modify a bit the code in order to get it work

1. Convert the JS file in typescript file
2. Add import

   import { Icon, IconOptions } from 'leaflet';
   import * as L from 'leaflet';

   export class FontAwesomeIcon extends Icon {
       // Add your JS code here
   }
3. Add an index.ts file:

   export { FontAwesomeIcon, FontAwesomeOptions } from './fontAwesomeIcon';

I've posted the code here: https://github.com/mylen/ngx-leaflet-fa-markers